# Generator in Haskell list comprehension not working

Tags: haskell, syntax, syntax-error, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list which will contain a list of solutions for the problem I am trying to solve. I am doing this using list comprehension, generating all possible combinations and then using a predicate to filter so that only solutions are included. Here is my code.

```
solveRow :: Row -> [Row]
solveRow (Row target rowCells) =
    [(cellsToRow target cls) | (cls <- (cellPermutations rowCells)), (result cls)==target]
```

`cellPermutations` returns `[[Cell]]` and therefore `cls` should be of type `[Cell]`. When I try to compile I get an error.

[image]

I thought `<-` passed each element of right hand side (in this case `[Cell]`) to the left hand side variable. Why am I getting a parse error for `<-`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don’t put brackets around `cls <- (cellPermutations rowCells)` — that’s a syntax error. You don’t need brackets around `cellsToRow target cls` either, although doing so isn’t an error. (And strictly speaking, you don’t need brackets around `result cls` either, but I personally think that those brackets make it more readable.) So your example should be:

```hs
solveRow :: Row -> [Row]
solveRow (Row target rowCells) =
    [cellsToRow target cls | cls <- (cellPermutations rowCells), (result cls)==target]
```